# Delete From JPA Query with Inner Join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I keep getting errors when trying to get this SQL correct for a JPA repository delete. What is the correct syntax?

```
@Query("delete * from TS t inner join TSC c ON t.tenantId = c.id where t.id= ?1 AND c.endDate < ?2")
    void deleteTSWithExpiredDate(Long id, Date date);

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:63)
```

**Another**

```
    @Query("delete t.* from TS t inner join TSC c ON t.tenantId = c.id where t.id= ?1 AND c.endDate < ?2")
        void deleteTSWithExpiredDate(Long id, Date date);

expecting IDENT, found '*' near line 1, column 10 [delete t.*
```

**Another**

```
        @Query("delete t from TS t inner join TSC c ON t.tenantId = c.id where t.id= ?1 AND c.endDate < ?2")
            void deleteTSWithExpiredDate(Long id, Date date);

unexpected token: from near line 1, column 10 [delete t
```

Comment: Hi Mike, you have a solution ? I'm faced with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for bulk delete is:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("delete Entity where id = :idParam");
// set params here
q.executeUpdate();
```

However from Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct), no joins can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the sub-queries themselves can contain joins.